# Exception handling on console application async code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, error-handling

Hoping that someone will be able to point me in the right direction. I have a console application that uses async method calls and I'm having a bit of trouble with the try/catch error blocks. Basically, when a catch is triggered it executes the logging code within the catch but it still throws the error up to the top level and terminates the overall execution of the app.

I've been looking through other queries about this and from what I've seen this type of behaviour can be caused by either an async void or an async Task with no await. Looking at my code I don't think I have either so I'm a bit stumped.

The error being introduced is a missing connection string (in the context file, not shown), which should throw a handled exception in the PayloadRepo method. Stepping through the debugger this error is indeed caught and logged as expected, however it still seems to bubble back up to the Main method and cause the overall execution to break.

Can anyone spot what may be happening?

Thank you!

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildLogConfiguration();
        BuildDependencyContainer();

        await RunProgram();
    }

    static async Task RunProgram()
    {
        systemLog.Info("Started full process at: " + System.DateTime.Now);

        using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var payloadService = scope.Resolve<IPayloadService>();
            await payloadService.ProcessPayloadData(scope);
        }

        systemLog.Info("Completing full process at: " + System.DateTime.Now);
    }

    public class PayloadService : IPayloadService
    {
        private static readonly ILog _systemLog = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public async Task ProcessPayloadData(ILifetimeScope scope)
        {
            await PayloadData_Process(scope);
        }

        private async Task PayloadData_Process(ILifetimeScope scope)
        {
            var repo = scope.Resolve<IPayloadRepo>();

            var payloadList = await repo.Payload_Get();
        }
    }

    public class PayloadRepo : IPayloadRepo
    {
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Payload>> Payload_Get()
        {
            using (var context = new ASGB_DataLayerContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    var payloadList = context.Payloads;

                    var result = await payloadList.ToListAsync();

                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) <<--- CATCHES THIS AND EXECUTES CODE WITHIN, BUT IT STILL THROWS AN ERROR ON RunProgram().Wait() AND TERMINATES PROGRAM
                {
                    systemLog.Error(ex.Message);
                    systemLog.Error(ex.InnerException);
                    var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
                    foreach (var entry in entries)
                    {
                        foreach (var prop in entry.CurrentValues.Properties)
                        {
                            var val = prop.PropertyInfo.GetValue(entry.Entity);
                            systemLog.Error($"{prop.ToString()} ~ ({val?.ToString().Length})({val})");
                        }
                    }
                    systemLog.Error("------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: `RunProgram().Wait();` - I stopped reading there. Make your `Main` a `static async Task Main` and do `await RunProgram();` - then reevaluate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Fildor, I didn't realise that the starting Main could be a Task. Unfortunately it didn't make any difference to the outcome though, it's still breaking at the same place.

Comment: Show the full error messages, both the one that is caught and the one in main.

Comment: OK, if this is out of the way, it should be possible to hunt the error down.

Comment: The error that is being generated is "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')". It is being caught and logged OK (as expected), however the program is then throwing it in the Main method and terminating, instead if handling it gracefully. Interestingly I did notice, accidentally, that if the connection password is wrong then it DOES handle it gracefully. It only seems to be if the context is not properly configured (e.g. missing connection string) that it fails completely. As a test, I tried wrapping the try/catch in ANOTHER try/catch and that DID handle it properly.

Comment: It therefore appears that it's nothing to do with the async/await aspect, it's just the way my error handling is set up on a basic level.